# Laravel log not showing system time

Tags: laravel

I seem to have a strange problem that I cant find and answer to.

When I run into any error in Laravel and I look at the log file, the time stanp shown in the log file is different from my system time.

Can someone help me fix this? 
How can I update Laravel to show correct time?

Comment: Does it only differ in hours or also minutes? It could be that your timezone is set wrong

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `app/config/app.php`
There should be a field called `timezone` in which you could specify app-wide timezone, including your logs to match your system timezone.